# How to use actuallymab\laravel-comment comments system?

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel and I'm trying to implement a comments system on some posts. I found a package which seems well supported and I thought I could save some time by using it rather than starting from scratch.

The packing is here:
https://github.com/actuallymab/laravel-comment

There are some usage details but they don't seem quite clear enough for someone at my level.

Where I'm at:

Composer done

Migrations done

in my "User" model:

```
use Actuallymab\LaravelComment\CanComment;
```

In my "Post" model:

```
use Actuallymab\LaravelComment\Commentable;


class Posts extends Model { 
  use Commentable;
  protected $canBeRated = true;
  //etc
}
```

In my PostsController I have:

```
public function comment()
{
  $userid = Auth::id();
  $postid = "1"; //static post id for testing

  $user = User::where('id','=',$userid);
  $post = Post::where('id','=',$postid)->first();

  $user->comment($post, 'Lorem ipsum ..', 3); // static comment for testing
}
```

And finally, my posts.blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.comment') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" id="commentdata"/> //not using this yet
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Publish" />
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('posts.comment') }}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, when I hit by submit button I get:

"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comment()"

So it seems I need to define a function in my User model? I'm not sure what to do here. I'm hoping some has used this package before.

**Update 1:**

I'm now using the following PostsController code:

```
public function comment()
{
  $userid = "1"; //static user id for testing
  $postid = "1"; //static post id for testing

  $user = User::find($userid);
  $post = Post::where('id','=',$postid)->first();

  $user->comment($post, 'Lorem ipsum ..', 3); // static comment for testing
}
```

The error remains as "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::comment()"

Comment: I'm wondering if it's something to do with the include:  

    use Actuallymab\LaravelComment\CanComment;

I can see that the files I need are under the vendor/actuallymab/laraval-comment/src folder but I'm not sure how the helpers etc are setup to point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

You can be almost certain when you receive this error it's because you've missed out a step: you're calling a method on the *query builder* not the *model*. You need to retrieve the model(s) from the query.

Here's your current code:

```
$user = User::where('id','=',$userid);
```

You need to retrieve the first model from the results, e.g:

```
$user = User::where('id','=',$userid)->first();
```

Although you can improve this by using the `find` method which accepts a primary key and returns the model, e.g:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
```

Then from there you're ready to create the comment:

```
$user = User::find($userid);
$user->comment($post, 'Lorem ipsum ..', 3);
```

---

Example of using the trait:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

use Actuallymab\LaravelComment\CanComment;

class User
{
    use CanComment;
}
```

Comment: I actually noticed that I missed out the ->first() just before you commented. I added it and it made no difference. I also tried your suggestion of using find($userid) and am still getting the same result.

Comment: Please update the question to include the code you're using now and the error message you're receiving,

Comment: I would guess then that the issue is you've imported the CanComment trait in your User class but you haven't actually added the trait, I have updated my answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had not import the CanComment trait in my user class. Additionally, I needed "protected $mustBeApproved = true;" in my Post model.